# Executing Altera project with WIFI

Tags: wifi, intel-fpga

I'm trying to executed a project made with Quartus on an Ubuntu 16.04 on a MAX 10 FPGA which is connected by WIFI with my computer, and I can't connect it by USB. I didn't find option on Quartus to be able to executed the compiled program with a wireless connection.

Questions :

- Is there a module to add on Quartus to add the wireless connection in the *Programmer* section?
- If it's not possible, which files must I transfer (using the `scp` command) and which one is the executable?

Comment: I am fairly sure that you cannot program a FPGA through WIFI using Quartus.
For the second question, what kind of OS do you have to use scp ? As you will need to install some driver to program the FPGA using the JTAG interface. The .sof produced by Quartus should be enough to program your FPGA.

Comment: @Stoogy I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04, and I know I can program on the FPGA using Quartus, just want to executed the project my card and I don't know if I can generated an executable file with Quartus (just have to transferring it , add permission and the work is done)

Comment: @Stoggy I found a way to create an executable with Quartus : go into the *Programmer* panel, *File* -> *Create JAM, JBC, SVF or ISC File* and choose the extension needed; after that, the JAM/JBC/SVF/ISC file is created inside the project folder and you have just to transfer this file inside your card